# org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException for "invalid drawable tag bitmap"

Tags: android

Ok, that's weird.

I've received this error for one of my activities, the weird thing is that the bitmap is used in every Activity! I don't even know how to reproduce the exception, it's working fine for me (and others I think).

This is the whole stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{it.enrichman.bolloauto/it.enrichman.bolloauto.activities.ArchivioActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class android.widget.ListView
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1872)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1893)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1054)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class android.widget.ListView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:250)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1742)
at it.enrichman.bolloauto.activities.ArchivioActivity.onCreate(ArchivioActivity.java:36)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1836)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
... 22 more
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/backrepeat.xml from color state list resource ID #0x7f020075
at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:1855)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:319)
at android.widget.AbsListView.<init>(AbsListView.java:632)
at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:164)
at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:160)
... 25 more
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #2: invalid drawable tag bitmap
at android.content.res.ColorStateList.createFromXmlInner(ColorStateList.java:146)
at android.content.res.ColorStateList.createFromXml(ColorStateList.java:129)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:1852)
... 29 more
```

The "missing" resource is this one (inside drawable folder):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/bg"
        android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

The "bg" drawable is inside drawable-hdpi (could be that a problem?), but as I said it's used in every activity as background!

The error is called during the setting of the layout:

```
setContentView(R.layout.archivio);
```

The xml layout is this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="BLABLABLA"
            android:id="@+id/archivioTextView" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:textIsSelectable="false" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="30dp" android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>
    <ListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/listaVeicoli" android:layout_gravity="center" android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

(Some of the useless statements are put by the Designer of IntelliJ!)

I've looked for similar problems but I don't have "strange" id like @+id/list or other problems that other users encuntered..

Any help on this? What am I missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the end I've found FINALLY the solution.
I've tried with different emulator and I was having this crash only with API 10 (2.3.3) or less. Looking around the xmls and trying to do different stuff (also copying the bg drawable everywhere, or changing id to my list) I've found this weird stuff in my custom theme:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/backrepeat</item>
<item name="android:colorBackground">@drawable/backrepeat</item>
```

This seems to be not a problem for newer android version but for older one yes.

Just remove the colorBackground definition (that maybe should be only a color) and that's it!

I hope this will help someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Create a **drawable** folder inside **res** folder.
Try keeping your **bg** inside **"res/drawable/"**.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Put your selector into the `res/drawable` folder and also give the `Listview` id as `android:id="@+android:id/list"`.

I hope it will help you out.

Thanks.